# Windows Time Zone Dropdown in C#

Tags: c#, windows, timezone

Is there a simple way to display Windows Time zone drop down in an application in C# so the user can change it?

[Similar to this Timezone drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJpW0.png)

Comment: You can set the timezone with `tzutil /s` or [via PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetTimeZoneInformation.html)

Answer (score 4):

I would do this as per the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/enumerate-time-zones).

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> tzCollection;
tzCollection = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

Then you could set a combobox DataSource equal to that collection like so

```
comboBox.DataSource = tzCollection;
```

Comment: It shows the UTC-12 as the default instead of the current time zone. How do I set it to current first and then make Windows accept the next timezone so the new timezone will be shown in Settings /Date and Time?

Comment: @BartDivanov This link should help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.local?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeZoneInfo_Local

Comment: The link did not help, but this link did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744707/adding-timezoneinfo-to-combobox-and-setting-seleteditem-baffles-me
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can set the comboBox to current timezone, but I do not see a way to set the system timezone based on the user's selection since TimeZoneInfo only gets information from the system date. Any suggestion on how to set the new timezone?

Comment: If you're just using the time zone in your application, then just hold on to the `TimeZoneInfo` object selected (or at least the `.Id` property).  If you mean you want to set the system-wide time zone setting, then see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25153145/634824).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I tried, but it did not work. Could this be that I supply the parameter taken from TimeZoneInfo as "(UTC-05:00) Havana" so when I used in SetSystemTimeZone() it does not do it? If so how do I get the name only from TimeZoneInfo ("Havana")? Note I take this string from a comboBox as shown above.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Another thing: There is a switch in Settings/Date & Time that set timezone automatically. How this setting will effect if I use your method?

Comment: You should pass the `Id` - not the `DisplayName`.  In a dropdown on the web, use the `DisplayName` to show to the user, and use the `Id` as the underlying value.  In a Windows app, you can bind to the `TimeZoneInfo` object, but then pass the `Id` to set the time zone, not the object's string representation.

Comment: The automatic DST setting should almost never be disabled in modern Windows systems.  The "dstoff" switch is an artifact from legacy days when we didn't have a complete list of time zones for the world.  Don't use it.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I need this for the desktop app (a wizard type app to setup the new machine), so I need to display the system timezones as they are shown in timedate.cpl app, not in the format of `TimeZoneInfo.Id`
 I use the following code to get timezone name from a combobox:
`string tz_selected = this.cboTimeZone.GetItemText(this.cboTimeZone.SelectedItem);`
How do I associate it with the `Id`?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I agree, but I was asking about the _Set Time Zone Automatically_, not the _Adjust for DST Automatically_ switch.

Comment: Ah, ok - sorry, I misread your question.  With regard to "Set Time Zone Automatically" - In most cases, that will do exactly what you want it to.  It uses whatever location information is available to the computer (IP, Wi-Fi, GPS if equipped) to select the time zone for the computer's location.  Works great when travelling.  Not so much if you use a VPN that gets its Internet from another time zone.  If your intention is to let the user pick a time zone from a list, you'll also want to disable automatic time zone, else you'll possible have the selection overridden.

Comment: You can do that by disabling the `tzautoupdate` Windows service.  [See here for various ways to disable a Windows service](https://superuser.com/questions/460076/disable-a-windows-service-from-the-command-line).

Comment: As for the dropdown, you are binding to `TimeZoneInfo` objects. `GetItemText` is calling `ToString` on the selected object, which in-turn gives the `DisplayName` property (identical to `((TimeZoneInfo) this.cboTimeZone.SelectedItem).DisplayName`).  So, instead, do `((TimeZoneInfo) this.cboTimeZone.SelectedItem).Id`.  Casting is required because `SelectedItem` is typed as `object`.