# Convert TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName to TimeZoneInfo.Id

Tags: c#, windows, timezone

I need to convert `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName` to `TimeZoneInfo.Id`.

I am getting the DisplayName from a combobox populated from names taken from `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`

Answer (score 0):

Get like this

```
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(t => t.DisplayName == displayName).Id;
```

Comment: It needs to be a type of TimeZoneInfo.Id (not var)

Comment: @BartDivanov var means `string` here. Type of `TimeZoneInfo.Id` is string. You can write `string` instead of `var`.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;`. `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` returns an iterable object. You can use Linq extension methods on this.

Answer (score 0):

Converting is not necessary, nor is it recommended.

`TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` returns a collection of `TimeZoneInfo` objects, *not strings*.

When you assign that collection to a combo box (assuming a `Windows.Forms.ComboBox` per our discussion in [the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743878/634824)), the combo box will *show* the `DisplayName` property of each `TimeZoneInfo` object, but the original object is retained.

All you really need is to get the `Id` of the `TimeZoneInfo` object that is selected by the combo box.

In other words, assuming you're populating the combobox like this:

```
this.cboTimeZone.DataSource = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

Then you can get the `Id` of the select item like this:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = (TimeZoneInfo) this.cboTimeZone.SelectedItem;
string id = tzi?.Id;
```

Or as a single statement:

```
string id = ((TimeZoneInfo) this.cboTimeZone.SelectedItem)?.Id;
```

Note that I use the `?.` operator, so that the resulting string will be `null` if there is no item selected, rather than throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Also - keep in mind that the strings of the `Id` property are intended to identify the time zone to the system.  Those strings will be the same regardless of the language settings of Windows.  The `DisplayName` string however, is intended to be human-readable, and will change to match the Windows language settings.